# SQLite TRIM same character, multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, trim

I have a table in an SQLite db which has multiple columns with leading '='. I understand that I can use...

```
SELECT TRIM(`column1`, '=') FROM table;
```

to clean one column however I get a syntax error if I try for example, this...

```
SELECT TRIM(`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, '=') FROM table;
```

Due to incorrect number of arguments.

Is there a more efficient way of writing this code than applying the trim to each column separately like this?

```
SELECT TRIM(`column1`,'=')as `col1`, TRIM(`column2`,'=')as `col2`, TRIM(`column3`,'=')as `col3` FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How [**SQLite**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#trim) guide tells:

> trim(X,Y)
>
> The trim(X,Y) function returns a string formed by removing any and all
>   characters that appear in Y from both ends of X. If the Y argument is
>   omitted, trim(X) removes spaces from both ends of X.

You have only two parameters, so it's impossible apply it one shot on 3 columns table.

The first parameter is a column, or variable on you can apply trim. The second parameter is a character to change.

Comment: So I must do them as separate TRIM calls?

Comment: You must call as separate TRIM calls, as you have written in your query

Comment: Thanks Joe. Calling them separately now. I noticed in another stack thread that using * in SELECT is not advised also, so imagine while this might seem the long winded approach, it is the more resource efficient one. Thanks.

Comment: @spcurtis81:Yes, if you use * wild card you can't operate on single field, so you can't apply tour trim logic. Have a nice day ;)